Filtering out a specific itinerary from the list of itineraries from OpenTripPlanner
Following the tutorial, I set up OTP 2.4.0 server with Portland area for routing requests. Now, when I use the Where-To feature I get a list of possible itineraries.
http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/plan?fromPlace=45.42069%2C-122.64557&toPlace=45.438529%2C-122.800189&time=12%3A16pm&date=06-25-2024&mode=TRANSIT%2CWALK&arriveBy=false&wheelchair=false&showIntermediateStops=true&locale=en
But now I want to get only a specific itinerary from this list. When I hit this url below(which I got from Inspect -> Networks in Browser)
http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/plan?fromPlace=45.42069%2C-122.64557&toPlace=45.438529%2C-122.800189&time=12%3A16pm&date=06-25-2024&mode=TRANSIT%2CWALK&arriveBy=false&wheelchair=false&showIntermediateStops=true&locale=en&itinIndex=2
in Postman, I still get a list of all the itineraries instead of the specific one I requested. Is there any way to filter this out?
